# I can't download YouTube app from icloud

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, youtube

I deleted the YouTube app about 3 or 4 months ago and I decided to download it again.
I went to the App Store and I looked for it and when I saw it the iCloud icon was not there, so I clicked on the app in the App Store. The iCloud icon is dull and when I click on it nothing happens!!! I tried uploading YouTube from Safari onto the home screen but still it just takes me to the website not the app.
I have a YouTube account and everything and I still get emails from YouTube but I can't download the app!!

Comment: Have you backed up your device to iTunes?

Comment: Check my answer, then check that your Parental Control settings are not set to lower than 17+.

Comment: What model and generation device is this? What iOS version?

Answer (score 2):

It's because the app is 17+. Go to your restrictions settings and enable apps above this age limit. Then try it again

Answer (score 0):

Use the App Store app to download YouTube onto your phone. If the iCloud icon is greyed out and nothing's working, try...

- **Switching your phone on Airplane mode and back off.**

To do this, swipe up from the bottom of your screen and tap the icon for an airplane. Doing this will turn the cellular radio and the Wi-Fi connector off and back on again.

On iOS 6 and earlier, where Control Center is not available (nothing happens if you swipe up from the bottom of the screen), do this from Settings. It's the first toggle switch.

- **Turning your phone off and back on again.**

To turn your phone off, hold the button on the top of your phone (or the one on the right-hand side if you have an iPhone 6 or 6 Plus) until a slider comes down. Slide the slider that appears to turn it off.

To turn it back on again, press and hold the button again, or plug the phone in if your lock button isn't working.

## After you do either of these options, go into the App Store and try downloading it again.

You should see the app downloading right onto your home screen.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open iOS App Store App
2. Press `Updates` for iPhone or `Purchased` for iPad in bottom menu bar.
3. Press `Purchased` at the top of the screen (only for iPhone)
4. Press `My Purchases` (only for iPhone)
5. Press `Not on This iPhone` or `Not on This iPad`
6. Find the App.

If that isn't working and you have updated your apps using iTunes

1. Plug your device into your computer
2. Click the device icon on the top left side of iTunes
3. Under `Settings` click `Apps`
4. There will be a list of Apps, scroll down to find YouTube
5. Click the `Install` Button
6. Click the `Apply` Button

If you don't see the app on iTunes, you may have to go to the iTunes App Store to download it. If the App says that it is downloaded, then click on `Purchased` on the right, click on `Not in My Library` and find it there, and then download it. Now go back up to the instructions for iTunes and you should at this point be able to get it back.

***One other thought crossed my mind. If you happened to have set, accidentally set Parental Control Settings for less than 17+, then you won't be able to download youtube. You will need to turn Parental Control Preferences off or set them to unlimited in order to get the app.***

Answer (score 0):

It's more than likely the age restrictions in general settings just lift the age restriction in restrictions ok. Karlos

Answer (score 0):

- The reasons could be either **Restrictions** check to make sure that you don't have a restriction to install an app that's rated for 17+ or **Compatibility** you'll only be able to install it on an operating system that's at least iOS version 8.0 or higher.
- If the above is true then you might wanna try to sign out of the App Store and then sign back in.
- If the latter is also true then I'd suggest you to perform a [Force Restart](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201559) on your device which usually works when the others don't.